# Observing Viewmodel Livedata in DialogFragment

Tags: android, mvvm, android-dialogfragment, android-viewmodel

I have a `Viewmodel` which has some `Livedata` parameters in it. One of those `Livedata` parameter's (`clickedItem`) change is designed to trigger a `DialogFragment`.

In `DialogFragment`'s `OnCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` method, I'm extracting and using the data in the said `Livedata` parameter to do a certain thing.

Here's the `clickedItem` observer method:

```
clickedItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { clickedItem ->
                if (clickedItem != null && !dialogIsDisplayed) {
                    showAddItemDialog()
                }
            })
```

Here's the `DialogFragment`'s `OnCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` method:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)

            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                requireActivity().layoutInflater,
                R.layout.business_inventory_selection_item_dialog, null, false
            )

            //Attach viewmodel to this fragment.
            setupViewModel()

            builder.setView(binding.root)

            bindView(viewModel.clickedItem.value!!)

            builder.create()

        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
```

And here's the `setupViewModel()` method:

```
private fun setupViewModel() {
        activity?.run {
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(BusinessInventorySelectionViewModel::class.java)
            with(viewModel) {
                itemBrand.value = null
                unitOfMeasurement.value = null
            }
        }
        bindViewModel()
    }

private fun bindViewModel() {
    binding.apply {
        businessinventoryselectionviewmodel = viewModel
        lifecycleOwner = this@ItemSelectionDialogFragment
    }
}
```

**The problem now is: When I try to use the data wrapped inside the `clickedItem`, I've found that it has data from the last time it changed and not the latest data that caused the `DialogFragment` trigger.
Before I get to utilize the latest data inside the `clickedItem`, I'm forced to go through all data that was ever stored in the `clickedItem`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this issue like this:

Instead of calling the `bindView(viewModel.clickedItem.value!!)` in `onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`, I called it in the `onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` method:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        bindView(viewModel.clickedItem.value!!)
        return binding.root
    }
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: I've put this as a self Q&A so that this might be helpful for someone who has faced this. Cheers!